# Does anyone know what CJMCU on breakout boards means?

Tags: board, breakout

I have recently been looking at a lot of breakout boards and noticed they have CJMCU in their description and even printed on them.

Initially I thought it may be an acronym and then thought it may be a brand but I have not been able to find any information at all.

Does anyone know what it means?

[image: CJMCU_Example]

Comment: http://cjmcu.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's just a brand name as pointed out in the comments by CL..

cjmcu.com

Comment: Looks like cjmcu.com website is no longer available.